# python groupby category column to create new count column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains two columns. One column contains name, the other contains different categories.

```py
import pandas as pd
data={"name":["Jack", "Mary", "John", "Derek", "Jack", "Jack"], "category":["c1","c2","c3","c1","c1","c2"]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I want to groupby name and category columns to create new columns for counts of each category for every person.

Desired Output:

```py
name  count_of_c1  count_of_c2 count_of_c3
Jack       2            1           0
Mary       0            1           0
John       0            0           1
Derek      1            0           0
```

Is there any functions in pandas to solve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: You want crosstab, `pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['category'])`